# creating a log with append

Tags: javascript, logging, innerhtml

need to create a log of messages where the message be saved along with the time.

I have this code, but the acresentar a new message is deleted the old and replaced by the new.

```
var textons = prompt("Digite sua mensagem para a ONS", "");
    var areaons = prompt("Digite a area onde o problema ocorreu", "");



    var date = new Date();
    var d  = date.getDate();
    var day = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;
    var mes = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var month = (mes < 10) ? '0' + mes : mes;
    var yy = date.getYear();
    var year = (yy > 100) ? yy - 100 : yy;
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var min = date.getMinutes();
    var minutes = (min < 10) ? '0' + min : min;
    var sec = date.getSeconds();
    var seconds = (sec < 10) ? '0' + sec : sec;     


    if (areaons != null && textons != null) {
        document.getElementById("logdescricao").innerHTML =
        "ONS: " + textons;
        document.getElementById("logarea").innerHTML =
        areaons;

        document.getElementById("loghoracos").innerHTML =
        day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

        document.getElementById("loghoralocal").innerHTML =
        day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
}
```

I thought about using the .append (function) but did not succeed.

how can I make the text stop being rewritten and pass to get saved?

thank

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you just want it to add to each section in stead of overwriting?
Then all you have to do is "+=" instead of "="

```
document.getElementById("logdescricao").innerHTML += "ONS: " + textons
```

However, this is probably not the best way of doing this.

You could try:

```
var logdescricaoText = document.createTextNode("ONS: "+textons);
document.getElementById("logdescricao").appendChild(logdescricaoText);
```

---

But, really, if you want to make a list of things, then you should be using a table. This will allow for much neater and structured styling.
In your HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Descricao</td>
            <td>LogMessage</td>
            <!-- other field headers like 'time' -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id=logs>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can use the javascript (inside your 'if' block, instead of all your ".innerHTML =" stuff)

```
var logLine = document.createElement("tr");
document.getElementById("logs").appendChild(logLine);

var descricao = document.createElement("td");
descricao.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ONS: "+textons));
logLine.appendChild(descricao);

var logArea = document.createElement("td");
logArea.appendChild(document.createTextNode(areaons);
logLine.appendChild(logArea);
etc..
```

Additionally, you might want to apply a CSS styling to the 'thead' part of the HTML

eg. in your CSS file:

```
thead {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```